# Azure AutoML: decimal numbers in confusion matrix

Tags: confusion-matrix, azure-ml, automl

I have been running Azure AutoML on a binary classification task. When I visualize the performance and the confusion matrix in particular, I observe the following:

[image]

How can I have decimal numbers in the raw confusion matrix? As per the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-understand-automated-ml#confusion-matrix): `A cell at row i and column j in a confusion matrix contains the **number of samples** in the evaluation dataset that belong to class C_i and were classified by the model as class C_j.`

Any insights, or pointers as to where I should look into to understand what is going on, is welcome!